# Prove that $(A \cap B') \cap (B \cap A') = A \cap A' \cap B \cap B'$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove that $(A \cap B') \cap (B \cap A') = A \cap A' \cap B \cap B'$.

I saw this result in an intermediate step in my book which was talking about De Morgan's laws. I didn't see how it follows from De Morgan's laws or anything else unless $A \cap (B \cap C) = A \cap B \cap C$.

Comment: What is it that you need help with? Do you know how to start? Let $x \in (A \cup B') \cup (B \cup A')$, then ...

Comment: If $x \in (A \cap B') \cap (B \cap A')$ then $x$ is in $A \cap B'$ and in $B \cap A'$, therefore it is in all four of the sets $A, B', B, A'$, and therefore...?

Comment: Does that mean $A \cap (B \cap C) = A \cap B \cap C$?

Comment: P.S. $A \cap (B \cap C) = A \cap B \cap C$ is indeed true. More generally, $\cap$ is associative and commutative, so you can remove parentheses and reorder at will.

Comment: So in your notation, is $A'$ the complement of $A$?  Of just some other set?

Comment: @GEdgar Yes it is the complement with respect to some universal set $U$.

Comment: In that case, you can try to prove both sides are equal to $\varnothing$.

Comment: @GEdgar user19405892 stated that this is an *intermediate* step in a proof, and just wanted to know how *that* one step worked.  (But yes, that is clearly being set to be the *next* step in the proof.)

Answer (score 1):

The binary set operation, $\cap$, is associative and commutative; so breaking it down into elementary steps.

$$\begin{align}
(A\cap B')\cap(B\cap A') ~=~& (A\cap B')\cap (A'\cap B) & \textsf{Commute}
\\[1ex] ~=~ & ((A\cap B') \cap A')\cap B & \textsf{Associate}
\\[1ex] ~=~ & (A\cap (B' \cap A'))\cap B & \textsf{Associate}
\\[1ex] ~=~ & (A\cap (A' \cap B'))\cap B & \textsf{Commute}
\\[1ex] ~=~ & ((A\cap A') \cap B')\cap B & \textsf{Associate}
\\[1ex] ~=~ & (A\cap A') \cap (B'\cap B) & \textsf{Associate}
\\[1ex] ~=~ & (A\cap A') \cap (B\cap B') & \textsf{Commute}
\end{align}$$

Which is a hectalot of clutter, which is why we abbreviate by just removing the parenthesis and rearranging a series of $\cap$-connected factors:

$$\begin{align}
(A\cap B')\cap(B\cap A') ~=~&  A\cap A' \cap B\cap B' & \textsf{Association & Commutation}
\end{align}$$